# Error JS send post data to controller -CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I'm developing a web application which is based on `CodeIgniter`. I'm new to javascript and JS development. I'm sending `post data to a method` which is located in a controlle r(**homepage/questionview**). The data I'm sending to the controller doesn't get posted to the controller. Attached you can see the code I am using. Every attempt I made triggers the AJAX `error` function.

**Html code inside the code I'm calling JS method called `viewQuestion(id)`**

```
<div class="col-md-7 column list-group">
        <a href=""  id="list" class="list-group-item active" onclick="viewQuestion(<?php echo $question['questionid']; ?>)">
                                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $question['questionid'];echo". "; echo $question['questionTitle']; ?></h4>

                                    <p class="list-group-item-text"><?php echo "Vote Count :"; echo $question['votecount']; ?></p>
                                    <p class="list-group-item-text"><?php echo "Asked user :"; echo $question['username']; ?></p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

**My JS code**

I double-checked the URL used and it's accessible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function viewQuestion(id)
{

   $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>homepage/questionview',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { listid: id },
        success: function () {
            alert('suc');
        },
        error: function (error) {
           // alert('error');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });


}


</script>
```

**homepage/questionview (controller)**

```
public function questionview()
    {
       //echo $listid;
      echo $this->input->post('listid');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

-make sure the onclick event is working, add a alert("test") before the ajax call to make sure you are getting there

-on your controller, try echo "test" to make sure you get the response

-use Chrome console to debug your ajax call and make sure its getting to the controller

Comment: And what you've got in each scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Put `return false;` at the end of the ajax code segment and see. Your code will be like this then.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function viewQuestion(id)
{

   $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>homepage/questionview',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { listid: id },
        success: function () {
            alert('suc');
        },
        error: function (error) {
           // alert('error');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

return false;

}


</script>
```